# Importing Eclipse project into Android Studio - getBuildScript error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I'm trying to import a project from Eclipse to Android Studio 0.28 and I'm receiving the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.gradle.tooling.model.GradleProject.getBuildScript()Lorg/gradle/tooling/model/GradleScript;
```

I've exported the Eclipse project using File -> Export -> Generate Gradle Builds.
Then in AS, File -> Import Project -> select the new "build.gradle" -> "Use gradle wrapper"

Am I missing a step?

Thanks in advance!

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
{
INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_45 
2013-09-12 07:44:40,471 [1565939]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_45 
2013-09-12 07:44:42,243 [1567711]   INFO - dle.util.AndroidGradleSettings - Found Android SDK home at 'C:/Mobile/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130514/sdk' (from local.properties file) 
2013-09-12 07:44:43,518 [1568986]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - org.gradle.tooling.model.GradleProject.getBuildScript()Lorg/gradle/tooling/model/GradleScript; 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: org.gradle.tooling.model.GradleProject.getBuildScript()Lorg/gradle/tooling/model/GradleScript;
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:151)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:126)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:76)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:87)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:44)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:53)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:130)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:407)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$1.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:454)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:468)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$6.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:279)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:207)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$10$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:676)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:434)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:151)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.gradle.tooling.model.GradleProject.getBuildScript()Lorg/gradle/tooling/model/GradleScript;
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.util.GradleUtil.getConfigPath(GradleUtil.java:176)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.createModuleData(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:442)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.createModuleInfo(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:416)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:251)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver$1.fun(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:133)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver$1.fun(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:126)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:148)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:126)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:76)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:87)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:44)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:53)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:130)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:407)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$1.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:454)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:468)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$6.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:279)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:207)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$10$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:676)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:434)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:151)

2013-09-12 07:44:43,520 [1568988]   WARN - ctExternalProjectImportBuilder - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.gradle.tooling.model.GradleProject.getBuildScript()Lorg/gradle/tooling/model/GradleScript;
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.util.GradleUtil.getConfigPath(GradleUtil.java:176)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.createModuleData(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:442)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.createModuleInfo(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:416)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:251)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver$1.fun(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:133)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver$1.fun(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:126)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:148)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:126)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:76)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:87)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:44)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:53)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:130)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:407)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$1.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:454)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:468)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$6.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:279)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:207)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$10$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:676)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:434)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:151)
}
```

Comment: I've found solution for this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007140/unsupported-method-gradleproject-getbuildscript

Answer (score 1):

**Fixed**:  I think I might have screwed things up by having a separate gradle installation in addition to whatever is installed by the Android Studio bundle.  I uninstalled gradle AND Studio, then just installed the default Studio build things worked better.  I still had to update the gradle value in the gradle-wrapper.properties file to "1.7" instead of "1.6".

But now all of my projects import correctly.

BTW, this was on Windows 7.