# Unsupported method: GradleProject.getBuildScript()

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I am getting this error while importing an adt project(after exporting and creating gradle file) into Android Studio on mac os x.

The android-studio version is 3.6 (latest) and the gradle version is 1.8 (latest).

The error shows up as:

> Unsupported method: GradleProject.getBuildScript(). The version of
>   Gradle you connect to does not support that method. To resolve the
>   problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you
>   connect to. Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read
>   other information from the model.
>
> Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

I have no idea where to look for IDE logs...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I was getting a similar error today opening a project after upgrading to Android Studio 0.3.6. Here is what I had to change to get it working again for me.

- Changed the following line in **gradle-wrapper.properties** from gradle-1.6-bin.zip to gradle-1.8-bin.zip

> distributionUrl=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-bin.zip

- Also changed the following line in **build.gradle** from 0.5.+ to 0.6.+

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'

In Windows, **gradle-wrapper.properties** is located at **\project folder\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties**

**build.gradle** is located at **\project folder\module folder\build.gradle**

The Files that Needed changed are highlighted in the project explorer screen shot below.

[image: Here's a screen shot of the project explorer in Android Studio with the files that need changed highlighted.]

After those changes I sync'd the project with the gradle files and then could build and test.

Hope that helps.

Note that you should use default or customizable gradle wrapper:
[image: gradle idea settings]

Comment: Hey LeftyCode ...now I am getting this error:   Gradle version 1.8 is required. Current version is 1.6. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Applications/Android Studio.app/bin/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-1.8-all.zip.

Please fix the project's Gradle settings.

Comment: Did you change the line in the gradle-wrapper.properties file (first thing I listed above)?

Comment: Thanks...missed that!

Comment: On windows, the path of **gradle-wrapper.properties** is at **your_project\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties**.

Comment: Thank you. It works on my mac. I changed **gradle-wrapper.properties** from 2.1.0 to 2.14.1 && **build.gradle** from 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.1' to 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta4'